# Python: Visibility of module-level variable depends of code using it

Tags: python, variables, module, global, variable-assignment

*config.py*

```
import json
import os

myfolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
configfile = os.path.join(myfolder, '../appconfig.json')
appconfig = None

def get_config():
    if myfolder is None:
        return myfolder
    if appconfig is not None:
        return appconfig
    else:
        #load the config
        try:
            with open(configfile) as json_data:
                c = json.load(json_data)
            appconfig = c
            return c
        except Exception, e:
            raise Exception("Cannot load config file %s : %s"%(configfile, `e`))
```

Now import it and use it:
*tmp.py*

```
import config
config.get_config()

python tmp.py                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 2, in <module>
    config.get_config()
  File "D:\projects\flask_ndc\lib\config.py", line 12, in get_config
    if appconfig is not None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'appconfig' referenced before assignment
```

Comment out line 18 in config.py

```
        #appconfig = c
```

Now the code works - (but of course without saving the content in the global variable)

Can somebody explain why the python interpreter is not able to see that the assignment of appconfig in line 18 refers to the module-global variable appconfig, declared in line 7 ????

Answer (score 1):

You problem is this line：

```
appconfig = c
```

It means define a new name in locals of function get_config.
So when Interpreter run this line:

```
if appconfig is not None:
```

It treat name "appconfig" as a local variable, but it is not defined in former local codes, so the exception cames out.

If you don't assign any thing to appconfig in function get_config, the Interpreter considers appconfig as a enclosing name, and use appconfig in module-level.

If you want to assign value to appconfig in function, just use "global" to declare， add

```
global appconfig
```

before the very first line appconfig appears.

Hope I can help you. Feel free to comment any other questions about this post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the reason of the error was clear to me, my question was rather why is the python interpreter behaving this way ? Is this a bug or a feature :) ?? 
Is there a reason for not checking the global scope at the time of the assignment?

Comment: Python's namespace has some diffenence from other languages such as javascrips or c. Variables defined in module is not global.  You can read this to get a brief view. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/beginners-guide-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-legb-anandh